# Bootstrap dropdown on navbar pushing content down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a dropdown option on the top navbar on bootstrap and it has one quirk, it pushes the content on the left of the navbar down as the navbar appears like so.

## before click

[image]

## after click

[image]

This is the html used

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Notifications</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/notification.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Image and text -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Bootstrap
      </a>

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Notifications <span class="badge badge-secondary">0</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default definition for a nav in bootstrap is to push down content.

**You can set`position: absolute;` on `ul`**

```css
ul{
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 14px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Image and text -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Bootstrap
      </a>
<div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Notifications <span class="badge badge-secondary">0</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: this fits my desired result nicely.

Answer (score 2):

```
.dropdown-menu{
position:absolute;
}
```

Making the dropdown as `position absolute`, will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the  contents within a single 'div' element as in the code segment below:

```
    <body>
    <!-- Image and text -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">Bootstrap
      </a>

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Notifications <span class="badge badge-secondary">0</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Seems to be based on bootstrap's documentation - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/. However, notice Samue's code, he probably doesn't want `navbar-toggler` button or maybe he has missed to include that.

Answer (score 0):

For icons in the top right of a webpage...

1. Make sure your CSS file comes **after** the bootstrap lib CSS file.
2. Insert the below code into your CSS file.
3. Add `id="dropdownMenu"` to your
   html tag. This should prevent the popup from going off the page while also preventing the navbar from ballooning out.

```
#dropdownMenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because bootstrap have `css` like :

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu{
    position: static;
}
```

To avoid the problem of pushing the content down on dropdown. **Just sipmly add `css`** :

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute;
}
```

in case your menus are on the right side and content gets overflow or not correctly visible then just simply add to

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
```

for getting menu dropdown to `align-right`